# 7zip filename encoding problems

Tags: linux, encoding, 7-zip, filenames, character-encoding

I have problems extracting files from 7zip archive with non-ascii symbols in filenames.

I have identical versions of 7z on two computers, which differ only by the system locale. If I compress on one computer and try to decompress on another, it fails. If I do this on the same computer, everything is ok.

Does anybody know what could be the reason for this and how this problem could be solved?

Comment: Try compressing the file with the `-mcu` flag to force UTF-8 encoding of the filenames (from the [7zip Revision History](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt), `4.58 beta`).  Also, what operating systems are you using?

Comment: linux linux linux

Comment: Have you experimented with changing the locale at either end with `LANG="...." 7za ....` so that the locale temporarily matches the one used at the other end? Have you verified that the filenames are really matching the expected locale? Could you post the output of `locale` from both systems?

Comment: I'm a little confused -- how does it fail?  What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot workout getting your non-unicode locale machine to work with unicode names, you could try having the first 7z stuff it into a "tar" first. That might hide the offending filenames on the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [AppLocale](http://learnmmd.com/Applocale7zip/) utility 
Or you can use [HotFix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2704299) Provided by Microsoft

Comment: Did you notice the OP is using Linux? (He should have mentioned it more clearly btw)